# Quaternion to Euler angles conversion

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems, rotations, quaternions

I have written the following MATLAB code for transforming Quaternion to Euler angles based on the mathematical formula from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Euler_Angles_from_Quaternion):

```
function [phi theta psii]=quat(q0,q1,q2,q3)

q_length=sqrt(q0*q0+q1*q1+q2*q2+q3*q3);

q0=q0/q_length;
q1=q1/q_length;
q2=q2/q_length;
q3=q3/q_length;

phi=atan2(2*(q0*q1+q2*q3),1-2*(q1*q1+q2*q2));
theta=asin(2*(q0*q2-q3*q1));
psii=atan2(2*(q0*q3+q1*q2),1-2*(q2*q2+q3*q3));

end
```

I tested the code:

```
[phi theta psi]=quat(0.99619,0,0,0.08716)
psi*180/pi
ans =

   -115.0435
```

The result is different compared to [this](http://quat.zachbennett.com/) website which suggests:

$\theta=0,~~~\phi=0,~~~\psi=-90$

Comment: Are the euler angles unique? There is also a [bult in](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/quat2eul.html) for this conversation.

Comment: @flawr, thanks. I dont have robotic toolbox. that's why i need to write the function.

Comment: Did you try Matlab File Exchange.  Seems like there are solutions up there: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=quaternion+to+euler

Comment: (1) As everyone else has said, this only works if you are dealing with a fixed rotation sequence. At the very least you should document the sequence you are assuming; that could be one source of error (2) There are MUCH better algorithms for doing this than what is listed on wikipedia. Google around more or if you can look at Markley and Crassidis' book on Spacecraft Attitude Control.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful when you convert between quaternions and euler angles. One of the main source of confusions are the conventions adopted to represent angles. The same quaternion can represent a rotation or it's inverse based on the adopted convention.

Your equations seems to be correct at first glance. As a comparison write some code to compute the conversion to the rotation vector. I do not know what the website does and I believe that when it comes to quaternions it is safe not to use software from different sources because you do not know the conventions that are adopted.

By the way, quaternions are provided by matlab in the aerosym toolbox (included in the complete version), but they follow the JPL convention and not the Hamiltonian.